# How can I reverse string contents by selecting multiple lines?

Tags: c#, reverse, record

I've found many resources online for reversing strings and entire text files, but nothing produces the result I want.

For example, the base text file might look like this:

```
1                                                 
Person One                                         
Company Name                                           
100 San Francisco Blvd, 000                                 
Dublin CA 94568                                   


2                                                 
Person Two                                       
Company Name                                               
111 Grove St, 000                                 
Montreal CANADA 93940
```

This is how the file would come in. What I am looking for is this:

```
2                                                 
Person Two                                       
Company Name                                               
111 Grove St, 000                                 
Montreal CANADA 93940 

1                                                 
Person One                                         
Company Name                                           
100 San Francisco Blvd, 000                                 
Dublin CA 94568
```

I have tried several solutions online and what usually ends up happening is one of the following:

1) The text is reversed. For example, Company Name becomes emaN ynapmoC.

OR

2) Something like this happens:

```
Montreal CANADA 93940 
111 Grove St, 000 
Company Name
Person Two
2
```

Things that are given are column length (I will always know how many lines there are in an address field), I will always know how many lines total. There is a blank space line between each record.

I am trying to figure out how to take filename.txt and flip it into filename-reversed.txt essentially.

TLDR: I want to take x amount of lines and reverse them so that they do not get mixed/jumbled up.

Comment: So, what do you need is to create an array of records from your string, right? and records in this string are separated by a double line break

Comment: Yes that's it exactly. I need to be able to take say for example 7 lines and reverse it with the other 7 lines. Each 7 lines is one record.

Comment: So what is the problem? The algorithm seems very straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var groups = Regex.Split(File.ReadAllText(filename), @"\r?\n\r?\n", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var newtext = string.Join(Environment.NewLine+ Environment.NewLine, groups.Reverse());
File.WriteAllText(filename, newtext);
```

Comment: @ryanyuyu It may look so to you, but no.. it does what OP expects :).

Comment: Care to write some explanation for the code?  Or maybe even a code demo?  The regex is a bit arcane.

Comment: Oh I get it.  It tries to match a literal newline followed immediately by another newline (which in the record appears as an empty line).  Probably worth explaining this.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't use .Reverse on groups? I understand the rest actually, this is pretty clever with the regex.

Comment: @rohanharrison `using System.Linq` ?

Comment: @L.B That makes more sense... Unfortunately I cannot use Linq for some reason that isn't apparent to me. When I import System.Linq it says that it cannot be resolved.

Comment: @rohanharrison Do you use an old .net version <3.5

Comment: @rohanharrison you don't need LINQ to reverse an array

Comment: @L.B WOW I must have accidentally changed the version or something at some point... It was set for 2.0. I honestly have no idea how that happened.

Comment: I've updated my .NET version and I tried your code and it did EXACTLY what I needed it to do. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the file into "records". Once you have records instead of just lines it should be a trivial task to reverse the order.

The simplest way would be to break your file into strings on every Nth line break. You can load those N-line strings into a list. Then just loop through the list in reverse and dump records into a file.

Answer (score -2):

in python:

```
blocks = []
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    block = ""
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        block += line
        if i % block_line_size == 0:
            blocks.append(block)
            block = ""
with open(new_file_name, "w") as f2:
    for block in blocks[::-1]:
        f2.write(block)
```

Comment: Question is tagged as `c#` **+**  this answer doesn't returns the output OP extects even in *python*